# How to read a character from standard input in DOS such that redirection works?

Tags: assembly, stdin, dos, x86-16, io-redirection

I am currently writing a DOS program. In this program, I use service [21/AH=01](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm) to read a character from standard input. However, it appears that when I redirect standard input from a file, EOF detection does not work as expected. I wrote this sample program in nasm syntax to illustrate the issue:

```
    org 0x100

    ; read characters and sum them up
main:   xor bx,bx

.1: mov ah,1
    int 0x21
    xor ah,ah
    add bx,ax
    cmp al,0x1a       ; eof reached?
    jnz .1

    mov cx,4
.2: mov si,bx
    shr si,12
    mov dl,[hextab+si] ; convert to hex
    mov ah,2
    int 0x21
    shl bx,4
    loop .2

    ret

hextab: db '0123456789ABCDEF'
```

When I redirect standard input from a file, the program hangs unless that file contains a ^Z somewhere. I was under the impression that EOF is marked with service 21/AH=01 returning ^Z in DOS, however, that does not seem to be the case.

How do I read a character from standard input in DOS in a way that works with redirected stdin such that the character is echoed to the screen in case input is not redirected and such that I can detect an EOF condition? Ideally, I would like to have something that behaves like the `getchar()` function.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you run real MS-DOS?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I haven't tried! Let me check tomorrow.

Comment: @MichaelPetch On real MS-DOS (I tested MS-DOS 6.02), mostly the same thing happened, except ^Z didn't even terminate the program when input was redirected. Another difference is that when input is redirected, it was copied to the terminal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the MS-DOS "read" function instead.  In general you want to avoid the old obsolete MS-DOS 1.x API functions.  The output functions (AH=1, AH=9) are usually OK, but most of the rest shouldn't be used unless you need your program to run under MS-DOS 1. MS-DOS 2.0 introduced a whole new set of Unix-like file functions that for the most part work just like the equivalent Unix function. So in this case MS-DOS read function, just like the Unix `read` system call, takes three parameters: a file handle, the address of a buffer and the number of characters to read. Just like with Unix, file handle 0 is for standard input, 1 is for standard output and 2 is for standard error.

So you could rewrite your example to use the MS-DOS read (AH=3Fh) and write (AH=40h) functions like this:

```
    ORG 0x100

main:
    xor di, di
    mov bp, buf
    mov dx, bp
    mov cx, 1

loopchar:
    mov ah, 0x3f
    int 21h
    jc  error
    dec ax
    js  eof           ; EOF reached?
    cmp BYTE [bp], 0x1a
    je  eof
    add di, [bp]
    jmp loopchar

eof:
    inc cx
    mov ax, di
    mov al, ah
    call printhex1
    jc  error
    xchg ax, di

printhex1:
    mov bx, hextab
    aam 16
    xlat
    mov [bp + 1], al
    mov al, ah
    xlat    
    mov [bp], al
    mov bx, 1
    mov ah, 0x40
    int 21h

error:
    ret

buf db  0, 0

hextab: db '0123456789ABCDEF'
```

Comment: @fuz The hex printing code is really too smart for its own good. It would only be faster than your code because it prints two digits a time. If you wanted shorter code then it would be better not to use the lookup table since the table is bigger than the code it replaces.

Comment: On the matter of _shorter_ code (Seeing `xchg ax, di`, you wrote it that way!): simply swapping `DI` and `BP` would shave off 3 bytes because `[bp]` requires a mandatory zero byte offset. Better still, storing the characters together shaves off yet another 3 bytes: `xlat` `xchg al, ah` `xlat` `mov [bp], ax`. Nevertheless an excellent answer (+) to the question of redirection awareness.